# Rails - class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have my app's mail setup as follows:

Step 1: 
Observers monitor tables, and send out emails when triggered by after_save in the observer

Step 2: 
The observer then calls something like: `UserMailer.XXXXXX_created_notification(record).deliver`

Step 3:
User mailer sends the mail out:

```
  def XXXXXX_created_notification(record)
    @record = record
    mail(:to => "#{record.email}", :reply_to => "Reply to XXXXX", :subject => "XXXXX Notification")
  end
```

My question to rails experts out there is, I want to provide users the ability to turn on/off certain site wide notifications. Where is the best place in Rails to bake this in? In the user_mailer.rb file wrapped inside the def above? Or in the observer?

Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I had to pick, I'd go with the observer however - most folks I've worked with would suggest moving this logic into the controller. There may be a number of cases where you don't want to fire off emails based on observed behavior - perhaps you're using these models in an admin context, or working with models via console, etc.